# How to determine dependencies of recipes in yocto?

Tags: package, dependencies, yocto

I want to add the `gedit` package to the the image. But I am not able to find the dependencies of the `gedit` package. How to find the dependencies (DEPENDS) in yocto?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the following command which opens up a Dependency explorer that displays dependencies on the packages:

```
bitbake -g recipe-name -u depexp
```

or `bitbake -g gedit -u depexp`, in your case.

On pyro and later use:

```
bitbake -g recipe-name -u taskexp
```

Note: this command needs python-gtk2 installed.

Comment: Note that depexp has been changed taskexp in Pyro and later.

Comment: With the transition to Python 3 and Gtk 3, instead of `python-gtk2` you now need: `gobject-introspection`, `python3-gi` and `gir1.2-gtk-3.0`

Comment: @pogojotz, please write a full answer. It's not clear where gobject-introspection, python3-gi, girl.2-gtk-3.0 apply. Cite some documentation to give context.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Toaster, which is a web UI that collects information about what you build, including dependencies. This video shows the dependency information provided:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-6dx4huNnw

Details on how to set up and use Toaster at

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/toaster-manual/toaster-manual.html

Comment: The latter link is now a 404. It seems the new location is https://docs.yoctoproject.org/toaster-manual/

Answer (score 0):

The list of packages installed in your image is stored in the manifest file (besides of build history which is already mentioned).

Content of the manifest file looks like:

```
alsa-conf cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.1
alsa-conf-base cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.1
alsa-lib cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.1
alsa-states cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 0.2.0-r5.1
alsa-utils-alsactl cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.5
alsa-utils-alsamixer cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4 1.1.2-r0.5
...
```

The list consists of the package name, architecture and a version.

That manifest is located in the deploy directory (i.e. deploy/images/${MACHINE}/). Here as an example of the directory listing (there are target images and the manifest file)

```
example-image-genericx86.ext3
example-image-genericx86.manifest
example-image-genericx86.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Can we get this without actually building the image?