# How to know who is included a particular recipe in yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

With oe-pkgdata-util, we can find out the recipe name of a particular file in root file system or given the recipe we can find out what all files it places in the root file system.

Is there any way to find out who includes a particular recipe into the image. For example i have the files of xserver-nodm-init recipe into my yocto image, but i have not added IMAGE_INSTALL += "xserver-nodm-init" in my local.conf, so is there any way to find out who has included this as their dependency.

Comment: `grep` is your friend here, Jamal.

Comment: Possibld duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34303946/2689839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can generate dependency graph using

```
bitbake -g <image>
```

it will generate dependency graph in dotty file format. You can view it in dotty or in a editor

Flattened recipe dependencies are saved to 'recipe-depends.dot' if needed to go into task level dependencies then looking into 'task-depends.dot' might be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by flattened recipe dependency

Comment: How can we get the dependencies in text rather than a graph?

Comment: `task-depends.dot` can be viewed as text file, its syntax is BNF format, you can also understand it like.

    "recipe1.task1" -> "recipe2.task2"

recipe1's task1 depends on recipe2's task2